# How to find locations of a single user in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Let's say I have these two models below and i want to get or fetch the location of a specific user using mongoose in node:

**User Model**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 50,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true,
},
password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 1024,
},
});
```

And **Location Model**

```
const locationtSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50,
},
lat: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
lng: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
user: {
    type: userSchema,
    required: true,
},
});
```

So, I tried to resolve it like this... but it didn't work.

```
const location = Location.find({
    'user._id': req.params._id
})
```

**How** can i return locaitons of a specific user?

Comment: import ObjectId and try the following:
const location = Location.find({
    'user._id': new Objectid(req.params._id)
});

this should work fine!

Answer (score 1):

The id you are trying to pass is a string, instead, it should be an object id

```
const location = Location.find({
    'user._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params._id)
})
```

It would work perfectly now.